# Python: issue with return statement

Tags: python, function, tuples, return

I'm currently learning to program in Python using Dive Into Python 3 book (among others). Below is the example from the 5th chapter of the book demonstrating the use of listing functions in order to pluralise words.

```
import re

def match_sxz(noun):
    return re.search('[sxz]$', noun)

def apply_sxz(noun):
    return re.sub('$', 'es', noun)

def match_h(noun):
    return re.search('[^aeioudgkprt]h$', noun)

def apply_h(noun):
    return re.sub('$', 'es', noun)

def match_y(noun):
    return re.sub('y$', 'ies', noun)

def apply_y(noun):
    return re.sub('y$', 'ies', noun)

def match_default(noun):
    return True

def apply_default(noun):
    return noun + 's'

rules = ((match_sxz, apply_sxz),
         (match_h, apply_h),
         (match_y, apply_y),
         (match_default, apply_default)
         )

def plural(noun):
        for (matches_rule, apply_rule) in rules:
            if matches_rule(noun):
                return apply_rule(noun)
```

The problem is that when i'm trying to execute the code in IDLE i dont get the correct result for words like "student" (words that have simple plural form-last rule). There is no problem with words that come under the rest rules.

Here is what i get form the interpreter:

```
>>> import plural
>>> plural.plural('copy')
'copies'
>>> plural.plural('hoax')
'hoaxes'
>>> plural.plural('beach')
'beaches'
>>> plural.plural('student')
'student'
```

The really really weird thing is that when I call the apply_default() function from the interpreter the job is done!

```
>>> plural.apply_default('student')
'students'
```

Comment: There's a typo in your source: `match_y` uses `re.sub` and not `re.search`

Comment: are you sure you're running the latest version of you code in IDLE? My guess is you didn't reload your code after your changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `match_y` function is wrong:

```
def match_y(noun):
    # return re.sub('y$', 'ies', noun)   # NO!
    return re.search('y$', noun)
```

It would always return a non-empty string, which counts as `True` when tested as a boolean value; so you applied the `apply_y` rule, which did nothing because there was no -y on your word, and returned the result (ie the original word).

Comment: Fixed. The refreshed eye is always helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `match_y` will always evaluate to True. Also, take a look at the documentation of re.sub:

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> ```
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement
> ```
>
> repl. If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl
>   can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash
>   escapes in it are processed. That is, \n is converted to a single
>   newline character, \r is converted to a carriage return, and so forth.
>   Unknown escapes such as \j are left alone. Backreferences, such as \6,
>   are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern.

Source:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html